# Objective-C Запись массива и корректировка содержимого

Tags: массивы, objective-c, структуры

Ребят, привет! Очень нужна помощь. Есть вот такая задача:

Создать файл, состоящий из структур с информацией о студентах. Структура содержит следующие поля: фамилия, количество оценок, массив оценок (не более пяти). Скорректировать содержимое файла по результатам пересдач неудовлетворительных оценок. В этом случае программа должна выдавать информацию о всех неудовлетворительных оценках и запрашивать новую оценку. Обеспечить просмотр содержимого файла.

Объясните новичку, как правильно записать массив в файл? И как скорректировать содержимое файла по результатам пересдач неудовлетворительных оценок?

```
#define N 20

void add_struct_func() {};

typedef struct {
char fam;
int markscount;
int marks [5];

} Students;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSMutableData *data;

    int k = 0, aN, i = 0; //кол-во заполненных ячеек массива
    Students main_struct[N]; //массив со структурами
    int neud_mass[N];
    BOOL O = 0;



    printf("Введите количетсво студентов\n");
    scanf("%i",&aN);

    for (i = 0; i < aN; i++) {

        NSLog(@"Фамилия: ");
        scanf("%s", &main_struct[i].fam);

        NSLog(@"Количество оценок: ");
        scanf("%i", &main_struct[i].markscount);

        NSLog(@"Оценки: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < main_struct[i].markscount; j++) {
            scanf("%i", &main_struct[i].marks[j]);

            if (main_struct[i].marks[j] < 3) O = 1;//проверка оценки
        }
        if (O == 1) {
            neud_mass[k] = i;
            k++;
        }
        O = 0;
    }

    data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&main_struct[N] length:strlen(&main_struct[N])];

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: @"/Users/Mix-roman/Desktop/ЛАБЫ/ThirdLabObjetive/test2.rtf"];
    if (file == nil)
        NSLog(@"Failed to open file");

    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData: data];

         [file closeFile];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону NSJSONSerializer для записи и чтения (если можно читать весь файл в память).

Comment: А может лучше просто воспользоваться C функциями fopen, fwrite, fclose ?